# Deployment of a .NET application making use of SQL Server 2008

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, deployment

I have searched the internet thoroughly for this type of issue, there were responses but hasn't really found a concrete solution yet.

I have an application which makes use of SQL Server 2008 R2 and thus it makes connections with a database file which I have set up. The application executes successfully, makes connections with the database and retrieves/inserts/updates data to and fro the database.

However when I come to create a deployment project i.e. a setup project, I fail to transfer my database files to other computers and make database connections. I have checked the SQL Server 2008 prerequisite in the publish settings of the application and has also included the database files.

Can anyone suggest the best way to this type of setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using all the built in Visual Studio stuff, it often generates a default connectionstring:

```
Data Source=|DataDirectory|\database.sdf
```

I would possibly try to change your connectionstring to an absolute file path to make sure it is actually able to find your database, its possible |DataDirectory| is not being translated into a findable path.

You also stated that it fails to transfer your database files to other computers and make connections.. I'm not sure if you mean your files are not existant, but if they aren't you need to make sure you included them in the File System portion of the Setup Project view, and that they are placed in the proper location (again, so |DataDirectory| translates and finds your DB, or you must provide an absolute Data Source path)

It would be more helpful in the future if you provided maybe a stack trace, exception details, or some sort of error message, something a bit more specific to go off of.

Comment: Actually - SQL Server CE is a one-file (`.SDF`) solution, running in-proc with your application (and thus inherently single-user). **SQL Server Express** is a regular .MDF/.LDF multi-file, multi-user, server-based solution

Comment: Ah, I was a we bit off on SQL Server CE, updated my answer, thank you.

Comment: I presume that DataDirectory is translated by .NET runtime and thus it is not the main source of the problem. I think the best way to solve this is to include SQL Server 2008 in prerequisites of the setup project... something which I have discovered after posting this question

Comment: In your original question you said you checked the prerequisite, which is why I pointed to checking your database location thinking you already included everything that's required. Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

try to enable TCP/IP under client protocols from SQL Server Configuration Manager to allow remote connection and check your firewall settings